# Which one is better? King's Rock or Razor Fang?

Tags: pokemon-series

In the pokemon games there are these two itens that essencially do the same thing (Apply a % of making the enemy flinch when attacking).
I wonder if there are differences in the percentage of flinching equipping the itens would generate.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are exactly the same in battle, as all items with the same description are, giving 10% chance to flinch to the attacks of the Pokemon holding them. The difference is that Gligar evolves up while holding the Razor Fang during a level up at night, and Slowpoke evolves while holding the King's Rock during a trade. If you don't play to use it as an evolutionary item, they are identical.

Answer (score 3):

Serebii says otherwise:

King's Rock is a + 10% flinch

Razor Fang is a + 11.7% flinch

---

Sources:

http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/kingsrock.shtml

http://serebii.net/itemdex/razorfang.shtml

Comment: looks like serebii has been updated and the two items are identical now. 10% each.